# Regular expression to match single first name string or first and last name string with one space and one hyphen

Tags: javascript

Regular expression to match single first name string or first and last name string with one space and one hyphen.

Valid matches

1. Mathias d-arras
2. Martin Luther
3. Hector-Sausage
4. Mathias
5. John-Paul Mathias
6. Jhon S
7. K Jhon
8. k jhon-m
9. J-m k
10. k j-m

Invalid matches

1. Mathias d arras
2. Mathias- darras
3. Hector -Sausage
4. Hector Sau K
5. Hector-Sau-K
6. Hector Sausage-
7. a-a aa-a
8. a-a aa a
9. Jean-Paul Simmons-Beckett
10. a-a a-a
11. a a a

Comment: Since you have the `i` modifiers, why do you have both `A-Z` and `a-z` in your letter classes?

Comment: You don't have hyphen in your character classes, so why do you expect it to allow them?

Comment: I want to allow only alphabets not numbers

Comment: I dont know how to construct for both space and hyphen

Comment: Is _Julia-Louis Dreyfus_ a valid match? My answer allows it, ImadOS's answer doesn't.

Comment: Can both first and last name have hyphen? My answer allows it in either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will correctly match the sample data that you provided (I'm assuming that you actually only want to allow spaces [], not all whitespaces [`\s`], which would also include tabs, line breaks, etc):

```
/^[a-z]+( [a-z][a-z-]+||-[a-z]+)?$/i
```

Though, I wonder if there aren't some other situations that you've missed in your sample data, such as:

- John-Paul Mathias *(valid, but would fail?)*
- Hector Sausage- *(invalid, but would pass?)*

There would need to be some more tweaks to handle those, if they are needed.

Also, I left out the `g` and `m` flags, since this looks like a pattern validation, in which case, I wouldn't think you would need them.  If you actually need to capture multiple instances of this pattern in a multi-line situation, then, you would need those flags put back in.

**UPDATE**

Okay, based on those other pieces of test data, the following regex will work:

```
/^[a-z]+-?[a-z]+( [a-z]+-?[a-z]+)?$/i
```

I keep feeling like there is a way to trim it down even more, but the complex relationship between the  and `-` characters are making it difficult.

**UPDATE #2:**

Updated to match even more sample data.   :D

```
/^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)?( [a-z]+(-[a-z]+)?)?$/i
```

**UPDATE #3:**

Okay . . . one more update, for the new "one hyphen" requirement.   :)

```
/^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+( [a-z]+)?||( [a-z]+)(-[a-z]+)?)?$/i
```

Comment: Yes it would fail for "John-Paul Mathias". What modification I need to do the regex which you provided.

Comment: Updated regex didnt work for 'Jhon S', 'K Jhon' and 'k jhon-m'

Comment: Ahhh . . . didn't see that you updated the sample data with more options . . . let me take a look.

Comment: Okay . . . updated to work with all of the current data samples.

Comment: Ooops now its allowing two hyphens. ex: 'a-a aa-a'.

Comment: Is that not valid?  Example:  `Jean-Paul Simmons-Beckett`

Comment: Its a invalid? Example: Jean-Paul Simmons-Becket

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm a little confused . . . in the example `Jean-Paul Smith`, "Jean-Paul" is a valid first name and, in the example `Mathias Simmons-Beckett`, "Simmons-Beckett" is a valid last name, but in the example `Jean-Paul Simmons-Beckett`, one of the two names is now invalid?  Which one shouldn't be allowed?  The hyphenated first name or the hyphenated last name?

Comment: only single hypen and space should be allowed

Comment: Okay . . . 4th revision added.   :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?(?:\s[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)$/gim
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?388tt)

Comment: It didn't work for these examples 'Hector-Sausage' and 'Mathias'

Answer (score 0):

please try this pattern :

```
/^[a-z]+\s?[a-z]+\-?[a-z]+$/gim
```

ok , i updated it for you

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?388u0) :P

Comment: `\w` allows numbers and underscores.

Comment: Why do you put `\w` inside a class by itself?